# Howdo I get rid of this error? illegal string in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I keep having this messages after updating some wordpress plugin:

Warning: Illegal string offset 'target' in .../public_html/wp-content/themes/woodmart/inc/shortcodes/info-box.php on line 144

Warning: Illegal string offset 'url' in ...public_html/wp-content/themes/woodmart/inc/shortcodes/info-box.php on line 147

I tried to reach the info-boh.php anf this is the code where the error happens:

```html
if( $attributes['target'] == ' _blank' ) {
            $onclick = 'window.open("'. esc_url( $attributes['url'] ).'","_blank")';
        } else {
            $onclick = 'window.location.href="'. esc_url( $attributes['url'] ).'"';
```

What can I do? someone has an idea?

Comment: `print_r` / `var_dump` the var `$attributes` for see if exist `['url']` and `['target']`

Comment: It means `$attributes` is a string and you treat it as an associative array. Where do you define this variable?

Comment: Thanks for helping but I don't understand :-(

Comment: What is `$attributes` and where do you assign a value to this variable? It's a string, not an array.

Comment: I do everything via the wordpress theme

Comment: Somewhere in your code, something is not being passed correctly. I would recommend learning the [basics of debugging](http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/basic-debugging/), because we can't help you based on this code alone. You need to find the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are getting $attributes['url'] empty. Please put is_empty condition before the comaring condition:

```
if(isset($attributes['url']) && !empty($attributes['url'])){
    if( $attributes['target'] == ' _blank' ) {
        $onclick = 'window.open("'. esc_url( $attributes['url'] ).'","_blank")';
    } else {
        $onclick = 'window.location.href="'. esc_url( $attributes['url'] ).'"';
    }
}
```